# Why is Google Chrome console uninformative when displaying arrays?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, javascript, console

Type on the console:

```
 a = [[1,1],[1,1]]
```

And you will see:

```
[Array[2],Array[2]]
```

That is as uninformative as it gets, and in order to understand your structure you have to click click click click (and don't expect a good formatting). I have to `JSON.stringify` every data before `console.log`ing. Why is it so uninformative, and can I config it for more usefulness?

Comment: Not a Javascript guru so this isn't an answer, but it looks like it's displaying the type of the object you just created. What would you expect it to print?

Comment: I'm complaining it overshadows the actual data. I expected just `[[1,1],[1,1]]`.

Comment: -1 this isn't really a very good question. How are we meant to know? Unless someone from Google has the knowledge, permission and desire to tell us...